# How to download a file from an email and save it in C:\

Tags: python, microsoft-graph-api, email-attachments

I have the attachment info ("contentBytes": "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAOEAAADhCAMAAAAJbSJIAAAArlBMVEX...etc) (from a graph API request) and below is the code I'm using to convert it, and this is a success, but I need to save it to the C drive. Is there something extra to add to this or should I be going in a different direction?

```
import base64
imgdata = base64.b64decode(contentBytes)
filename = "sample.png"
with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(imgdata)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the save location just write the path along with the filename
By the way, the code isn't working properly because `contentBytes` isn't defined so it'll give an error

```
import base64

imgdata = base64.b64decode(contentBytes)

filename = "C:/users/user/path/to/save/file/to/sample.png"

with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
   f.write(imgdata)
```

This should save the file to the chosen directory

Comment: Oh wow I was so close! I swear I tried that but originally didn't work - Thank you!

Comment: No problem glad to help!